# Android and Perl

Tags: android, perl

What are the advantages / disadvantages of using Perl to
develop Android applications instead of Java?

See: http://codatech.us/index.ftl

Answer (score 4):

Disadvantages:

- Anyone using your app will have to download Perl.  While you might be able to bundle it nicely (this is a goal of the Perl on Android project, and I'm not sure how far it has come), it will still make your filesize a lot bigger.
- I don't have any personal experience with it, but from a distance it looks like it is still highly experimental.

I'm a huge fan of Perl (and don't even know Java), but if I were considering Android App development, I don't think I would consider this a serious option.

The main page of the perldroid project is [here](http://code.google.com/p/perldroid/), by the way.

The project you have linked to is an entirely different matter.  It also looks like it is in the experimental stage.  I'm not convinced that it is useful, either.